# Command cd stoped to work in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, bash

On a regular basis I change to Desktop using the command cd in a Terminal. But from a few days ago when I use the command cd in a Terminal to change to Desktop, like the following line:

```
cd /home/myname/Desktop
```

I am getting the following message:

```
bash: cd: /home/myname/Desktop : No such file or directory
```

But when using  cd to change for Downloads for example:

```
cd /home/myname/Downloads
```

the command works properly. It seems like somehow the link to Desktop was missed. Can anybody help me to fix this problem?. I'm sure the problem is not with the path because I have ever used this way.

Here is the output to `ls -l /home/myname | grep Desktop` as Wayne_Yux asked:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 myname myname 4096 Nov 6 13:52 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 30 myname myname 4096 Nov 2 09:09 Desktop
```

Comment: can you please [edit] your question and include the output of `ls -l /home/myname`? or `ls -l /home/myname | grep Desktop`, if the former is very long

Comment: Done Wayne_Yux.  Now you can see the requested output in the question.

Comment: David, how about this? ls | LC_ALL=C sed -n l | grep Desktop

Comment: Hi tweej.  The output to yours was:  Desktop$

Comment: @DavidStalin there were really two lines in the output? This should not happen, because Ubuntu does not allow duplicated file names... Can you check, if one of those has a space at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I think creating this dir with `mkdir -p /home/myname/Desktop` is the only way. Maybe you removed it accidentally.

Comment: Yes Anton, I did it. Now I can change to Desktop using cd. But if I want to change to /home/myname/Desktop/Sage/sage-5.10 I have also to execute your suggested commend. I did it because I need to run the software Sage, which I usually did by changing to sage-5-10 and then command ./sage and the sage will run. But now I commited the error of running your command this way:

Comment: mkdir -p /home/myname/Desktop/Sage/sage-5.10/sage

Comment: Now when typing ./sage I get the result                                                                 bash : ./sage: Is a directoy  .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           How can I undo thid?.

Comment: Also when I shut down the computer and reboot the result of applying mkdir is "forgotten" and again I can't change using cd.